# function work window resize

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code

```
var bodyWidth = ($(document).width()/2);
console.log(bodyWidth);
$('.freeshipping').css('right',bodyWidth);
```

Its is fine , but i want work this function body resize and page refreshing . How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
   var bodyWidth = ($(document).width()/2);
   console.log(bodyWidth);
   $('.freeshipping').css('right',bodyWidth);
});
```

and if you need to execute also once (without explicit resize action) chain the `trigger()` method

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
   var bodyWidth = ($(document).width()/2);
   console.log(bodyWidth);
   $('.freeshipping').css('right',bodyWidth);
}).trigger('resize');
```

since you're targeting a DOM element `$('.freeshipping')`, be sure to wrap this snippet at domready event

Comment: Thanks, also need to work this function when i am refreshing the page,

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var bodyWidth = ($(document).width()/2);
    console.log(bodyWidth);
    $('.freeshipping').css('right',bodyWidth);
});
```

**UPDATE:** Calls function once:

```
$(window).resize((function(){
   var bodyWidth = ($(document).width()/2);
   console.log(bodyWidth);
   $('.freeshipping').css('right',bodyWidth);

   return arguments.callee;
})());​
```

Comment: Thanks, also need to work this function when i am refreshing the page,

Comment: I'm gonna like this one, this one is interresting and has brain behind it! =) Nice solution @Engineer! =) I like these self-invoking anonymous functions although when they are many, it's hard to maintain them, but the thought is nice! =)

Comment: Keeps the UI and the memory free from "not-oftenly-running" methods.

Comment: i got the code from other place, now its working both time, page refreshing and resizing ,  anyway thanks for your help , if want to see that code just ask me, thanks again

Comment: @ShibinRagh My updated code works on page refreshing and resizing . You could try it also.

Comment: It's not working, i check mozilla firebug console , there is a error which saying "illegal character" , what is it?

Comment: @ShibinRagh It works -> http://jsfiddle.net/uJXHz/ ...You need to add the code in `$(document).ready`'s callback

Comment: Not working here, please check firebug console with your code

Comment: @ShibinRagh Look at this-> http://goo.gl/qs5rk

Comment: this is you code ,  http://i49.tinypic.com/315odhw.jpg

Comment: @ShibinRagh There is no symbols after `'})());'`.Those symbols are not part of `Javascript​`. Why do I need to add them ?!! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11381/discussion-between-shibin-ragh-and-engineer)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
     var bodyWidth = ($(document).width()/2);
    console.log(bodyWidth);
    $('.freeshipping').css('right',bodyWidth);
    });
```

more info: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Thanks, also need to work this function when i am refreshing the page

Comment: use F. Calderan code to trigger event

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so everybody has answered the question which is fine, but!
Here is another sample:

```
    //store temporarily the existing method
    var resize = $.fn.resize;

    //overwrite $(window).resize with your method
    $(window).resize(function () {

        //here you do your stuff
        stuff.setWidth(param);

        //call the original
        resize;
    });
```

The difference is that you already have a `$(window).resize(function () { /* ... */ });` method which you don't want to loose, only to extend.
I have across this issue when I was writing my own jQuery plug-in. I have had to consider existing $(window).resize() methods added by the user/developer. So this way I preserve it and run the methods/functions I need to update my own plugin.

Comment: Thanks, also need to work this function when i am refreshing the page, clear?

Comment: When you refreshing a page, you loose your (existing) data. You can store it in a cookie if you like, or in the localStorage (HTML5 solution, key > value array) if the browser supports it. Or store it in the DB on the server-side if you have any, and when the page loads, query it.